# calling a webservice error

Tags: javascript, html, web-services

I am trying to follow the this tutorial ( http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/CallWebServiceFromHtml.aspx ) and learn to call a web service from a web page. However, I´m getting an error in the Firebug console:

> service is not defined
>   InitializeService() onload() event =
>   load
>   service.useService("http://tm.a...smx?WSDL",
>   "TryggMedisinWebService");

This is the relevant code I´m using.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
         function InitializeService() {
          service.useService("http://tm.arnett.no/tryggmedisinwebservice/tryggmedisinwebservice.asmx?WSDL", "TryggMedisinWebService");
         }

         var spm, kategori, fylke;

         function SendQuestion(){
          spm = document.send_question.spm.value;
          kategori = document.send_question.kategori.value;
          fylke = document.send_question.fylke.value;
          service.TryggMedisinWebService.callService("Send_Question", spm, kategori, fylke);
         }
         function ShowResult(){
            alert(event.result.value);
          }
    </script>

<body onload="InitializeService()" id="service" style="behavior:url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/webservice.htc)" onresult="ShowResult()" <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

I would appreciate any help i can get on troubleshooting this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is using `.htc` file and as far as I know it's supported only by IE browsers.

To have it work in other browsers, switch to using ordinary AJAX - for example jQuery provides excellent interface.

Here is link to good article explaining how to consume web service using jQuery:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sridhar_subra/116/
Didn't personally test it, but from what I've seen the information there is accurate and to the point.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide a link to get me started?